# NSD discovery not finding anything in Motog3 API 23

Tags: android, nsd

I'm having a strange behaviour in a MotoG3(API 23) device when doing the Nsd discovery. Both the discovery from NsdManager and the library https://github.com/andriydruk/RxDNSSD are not discovering any service.

I verified services are available in the network that the device is connected to. When trying the same thing in a device with Android N the discovery works well. 
Most importantly this discovery worked previously and it suddenly stopped working. I think something in the network could've changed but I do not  know what it is.

Also trying the search on another network with services worked well in original device. So it is possible that some configuration of the network makes the discovery in the MotoG3(API 23) not find anything. Can't determine if it is a device or a API problem because I do not have a different device with same API to test this on.

To verify it was not an implementation mistake I downloaded
ZeroConf Browser and it wasn't able to find services.

So my question is: Does anybody know what could be the cause of this or if there is any solution to make it work?